# Simple code to write differential equations in a matrix formulation

Tags: differential-equations, matrix

Is there a simple code to transform the following differential system equations :

```
SysDiff = {Subscript[F, x] == m Subscript[x, G]''[t],
    -g m + Subscript[F, y] == m Subscript[y, G]''[t], 
    1/2 l Sin[γ[t]] Subscript[F, x] - 1/2 l Cos[γ[t]] Subscript[F, y] == JG γ''[t]}
```

In a matrix formulation such as:

$$M q''(t) + \phi_q^{\mathsf{T}}*Lambda = F $$

where $q = \{γ[t], x_G[t], y_G[t]\}$ is a vector with 3 components,

and $Lambda = \{F_x, F_y\} $ is a vector with 2 components.

P.S: For a better understand, these equations are those of a simple pendulum with absolute coordinates and the constraints equations are:

```
SysCon = {-(1/2) l Cos[\[Gamma][t]] + Subscript[x, G][t] == 
   0, -(1/2) l Sin[\[Gamma][t]] + Subscript[y, G][t] == 0}
```

In others words, for the equations given, how can I determine :

- the matrix M
- the matrix $\phi_q^{\mathsf{T}}$,
- the vector F ?

Comment: What is Lambda? Subscript[\[Phi], Subscript[q]] makes no sense. Is it Subscript[\[Phi], q]? Then what is $\phi$.

Comment: The second line of code should be written as `M.D[q[t], t, t] + Subscript[ϕ, Subscript[q]].Lambda == F`, and the second `Subscript` probably should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SysDiff = {
Subscript[F, x] == m Subscript[x, G]''[t], 
-g m + Subscript[F, y] == m Subscript[y, G]''[t], 
1/2 l Sin[γ[t]] Subscript[F, x] - 1/2 l Cos[γ[t]] Subscript[F, y] == JG γ''[t]};

eqns = SysDiff /. Equal[lhs_, rhs_] :> lhs - rhs;

q = {γ[t], Subscript[x, G][t], Subscript[y, G][t]};

c = Thread[
 Join[q2 = D[q, {t, 2}], λ ={Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y]}] -> 0];
```

The resulting matrices:

```
M = D[eqns, {q2}] /. c
```

> {{0, -m, 0}, {0, 0, -m}, {-JG, 0, 0}}

```
Subscript[ϕ, q] = Transpose[D[eqns, {λ}] /. c]
```

> {{1, 0, 1/2 l Sin[γ[t]]}, {0, 1, -(1/2) l Cos[γ[t]]}}

And the r.h.s vector:

```
(*rhs F*)f = -eqns /. c
```

> {0, g m, 0}

Comment: The formulation of my differential equations is right. It is the differential equations of a multibody systems with kinematic constraints. But, I have forgotten the transpose on the jacobian matrix. May you help me to correct it in my question ? I have difficulties to write a supercript in tex.

Comment: What are the kinematic constraints in SysDiff. It cannot be the last one as it seems to contain force terms. But now I understand what you mean by $\lambda$ - a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: OK. Sorry. I better understand you remarks. Lambda is indeed a Lagrange Multiplier. The vector Lambda corresponds in my case at the reactions force {Fx,Fy} and in my formulation with matrix the F vector is in fact {0,-m*g}. Concerning the kinematic constraints, I didn't give them here. Thank you for your help

Comment: I have corrected the definition of Lambda in my question

Comment: I think it is very confusing to be using $\lambda$ and the Jacobian of the constraints $T$ when constraints are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: This is how the equations are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibody_system#Equations_of_motion. You don't have constraint equations in the question (so λ is irrelevant as of now) and I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: So now the formulation in the question is the same as wiki exempt that the jacobian matrix (linked to the partial derivate of constraint) is written phi_q instead of C_q

Comment: No! You left out the $Q_v$ in the wiki (which I have above as $Cv$). And again, to repeat myself, your $\phi_q$ (what is $C_q$ in the wiki) and $\lambda$ are completely irrelevant here. You haven't said what the constraints here. How can anyone here compute its Jacobian??

Comment: I understand your remarks. But, in multibody systems with holonomic joints, Qv is not present and it is the case I study. For the jacobian, you don't need to compute it because you can find the coefficients thanks to the question. But , I will add it as a remark in the question.

Comment: Phew, I think I have finally understood your question. You just need to compute M and $\phi_q$. I will shortly update my answer. Why on earth did you use notation for force to denote Lagrange multipliers? That really threw me off.

Comment: In fact, it comes from the fact that I uses Newton-Euler formulation instead of Lagrange equations so as to obtain the equations. But, the reaction forces corresponds to the Lagrange multipliers that we obtain with the Lagrange equations.

Comment: Fair enough. It all makes sense now.

Comment: Perfect, I test it and it works well. I only need to better understand this line : c = Thread[
 Join[q2 = D[q, {t, 2}], λ ={Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y]}] -> 0]; May be it is the join function which causes me trouble. In fact, by the past, I have only used Thread like this : Thread[Vector1=Vector2]. May you bring me a short information so that I can better understand this line.

Comment: It is basically this: q2 = D[q, {t, 2}];  \[Lambda] = {Subscript[F, x], Subscript[F, y]};  e = Join[q2, \[Lambda]];  c = Thread[e -> 0]. You used Equal and I used Rule for 'function' in Thread[function[list1, list2]]. If list1 or list2 is not a list it is expanded to a list of identical elements.

Comment: Suba Thomas May you help me to also make a automatic process so as to determine the vector F ?

Comment: May help me to also make a automatic process so as to determine the vector F ? @Suba Thomas